# Expand QListWidget in QDockWidget in a QGIS plugin

Tags: qgis, python, qt

I am working on a QGIS plugin. The plugin has a panel with two `QListWidget` and buttons, labels, etc. I would like to expand horizontally and vertically the lists if panel resized. I set the `hsizetype` and `vsizetype` to Expanding for both lists. Unfortunately lists are not expanding vertically after a given size. What should I change in the Qt ui file to expand lists?

You can find my ui file here: https://github.com/zsiki/thematics/blob/master/thematics_dockwidget_base.ui

[image]

**Additional information**

Following Kadir's answer I had to change verstretch to 1 for the main widget  (QDockWidget) to get the desired behavior of my panel.

Answer (score 4):

Change `verstretch` value from 0 to 1 for two `QListWidget`s.

```xml
<widget class="QListWidget" name="list_projects">
  <property name="sizePolicy">
    <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
      <horstretch>0</horstretch>
      <verstretch>1</verstretch>  <!-- change to 1-->
    </sizepolicy>
  </property>
</widget>
```

Comment: Thanks, if I set verstretch to 1 on both lists the expansion is not balanced, first list is expanded more. I would like balanced expansion. List are expanded horizontally without horstretch set to 1.

Comment: I add comment to my question, thanks.